# Have Apple ceased selling Mac Pros in the UK?

Tags: mac-pro, apple-store

I thought I'd look into the specs and price of a modern Mac Pro here in the UK, but there's no mention of them on the official Apple website. Stranger still, they're listed where you'd expect them to be on the US site.

Have they stopped selling them in the UK?

**US STORE:**

[image]

**UK STORE:**

[image]

Comment: Downvoted? What possible reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Apple announced to resellers and the press in late January 2013 that as of March 1, 2013 the Mac Pro will no longer be sold in the EU.

There are several articles explaining why and the rumors surrounding what may be next:

- http://www.macworld.com/article/2026780/mac-pro-sales-to-stop-march-1-in-eu-countries.html
- http://9to5mac.com/2013/01/31/apple-to-discontinue-mac-pro-in-europe-in-march-over-new-product-certification-standards/
- http://www.loopinsight.com/2013/01/31/apple-confirms-mac-pro-sales-will-cease-in-eu-on-march-1/

Whether you choose to interpret the [news that Tim Cook has emailed one customer](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/06/12/tim_cook_confirms_updated_mac_pro_coming_in_2013/) as to whether Apple has planned a new version of the Mac Pro or perhaps some other new computer or service that will make people who wanted to buy a Mac Pro happy is open for debate.

Since Apple hasn't announced anything to take it's place, and heck, Apple isn't even putting a notice on it's web site about the withdrawal and instead just removed the "buy now" button and removed it from the online store is all that we on the outside can see today.

It's unclear if you can import the machine with the new regulations in effect, but I would presume the used market is unaffected and you can still seek repair service for existing and imported Mac Pro (for a while at least) but no longer buy a new one from Apple while within the EU.

Comment: Well oddly the Mac Pro IS still listed on the UK site... you just can't buy one: http://www.apple.com/uk/macpro/

Comment: Yes - I firmed up the wording of what they have done since clearly, some people are still buying the Mac Pro in other regions around the world and although Apple apparently can't or won't keep selling it with the existing internal fan design in the EU, it's clearly also something that's very much still for sale in the rest of the world.

Comment: `with the new regulations in effect` - are you able to elaborate on what that means?

Comment: @MarkHenderson the [linked 9to5 Mac article](http://9to5mac.com/2013/01/31/apple-to-discontinue-mac-pro-in-europe-in-march-over-new-product-certification-standards/) has the full story. Briefly, it's attributable to `these systems are not compliant with Amendment 1 of regulation IEC 60950-1, Second Edition`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 2 months ago.

Ref: [Apple to Halt Mac Pro Sales in Europe Effective March 1 Over Regulatory Requirements](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/31/apple-to-halt-mac-pro-sales-in-europe-effective-march-1-over-regulatory-requirements/)

And no it shouldn't be forever, just until the new generation of Mac Pro comes out. That's IF Apple release a new generation of Mac Pros...

Comment: Wow. Really? They're insanely expensive, but they're so well made (internally) that I almost want one just because of how nice the case is. Almost.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt The Mac Pro does amazing things in a few very niche markets. Also, when someone starts with a Mac Mini server and grows and wants to keep one point of service, support - the Mac Pro makes great economical sense. When you don't need workstation class internal storage or can't wait for thunderbolt to supplant the very real use of high speed PCI expansion in some vertical markets - the Mac Pro is still a workhorse for many. Compared to other servers, the Mac Pro has ram and CPU adoption delay that make is very uncompetitive not to mention that it missed the thunderbolt train.

Comment: @bmike I work on Mac Pros connected via an X-Serve, and we sometimes use them for rendering, but they're no quicker than a PC kitted out to the same spec -- and insanely more expensive. I'd love to hear an example of something "amazing" they do.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Commercial iOS development, people who used to run Xserve and need something newer than Xserve, medical kiosk verticals. Hardware isn't the main cost in these applications and when you are billing by the hour, support and running OS X can be make-or-break.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler If the Mac Pro does come back to Europe it will be in the form of a Mac Pro Mini, from what I read when it was initially announced.

Comment: @bmike Sure, but you don't need a $3500 machine to run OSX, or indeed, do any of those tasks better than you could on a cheaper Mac.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt You seem to be interpreting the converse of what I was saying. Some people use OS X as a reason to buy a Mac Pro. I don't see it following that anyone needs a Mac in the first place let alone a Mac Pro :-) Are we in agreement than a $3500 computer is generally uncompetitive? That's my main point in case you missed it.

Comment: @bmike Haha! Sorry, I did miss it. I thought you were contradicting my statement about them being expensive. Yes, as wonderfully constructed as they are (and they're just *beautiful* inside), they're far too much for what you get from them in a practical sense. 

Makes me wish that some Motherboard manufacturers would start co-ordinating with Case manufacturers. It would be wonderful if such beauty was more affordable.